# WooCommerce REST API aborts connection

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

I'm engaging with the Woo Commerce API via Python. I keep getting a strange error, when my program has iterated through about 190 products, the requests module returns an error: `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))`. The error isn't very descriptive. But I genuinely don't understand why it would abort the connection, when it has been able to contact the REST API endpoints for the other 190 products before it. This is the code where it seems to error:

```
def create_tag(tag_name: str, api_object):
    print("create tag...")

    data = {"name": tag_name}
    tag_data = requests.post("{url}/wp-json/wc/v3/products/tags".format(url=api_object.url), auth=(api_object.consumer_key, api_object.consumer_secret), data=data).json()
    return tag_data
```

I don't believe the code is incorrect, but I can't understand why the connection gets aborted. Here's the full trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 414, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
OSError: [Errno 0] Error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 769, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 414, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/atlsoft/commercelink/apps/AVWOITEMS.py", line 57, in start
    batch_items["create"].append(product_check(wooapi, item))
  File "/home/atlsoft/commercelink/apps/AVWOITEMS.py", line 33, in product_check
    category_id = woo.category_check(item.category, wooapi)
  File "/home/atlsoft/commercelink/platforms/woo/woo.py", line 136, in category_check
    category_id = create_category(category, prev_category, api_object)
  File "/home/atlsoft/commercelink/platforms/woo/woo.py", line 100, in create_category
    return requests.post("{url}/wp-json/wc/v3/products/tags".format(url=api_object.url), auth=(api_object.consumer_key, api_object.consumer_secret), data=data).json().get("id")
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 547, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 414, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
OSError: [Errno 0] Error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 769, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 414, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/atlsoft/commercelink/apps/AVWOITEMS.py", line 73, in <module>
    start(user)
  File "/home/atlsoft/commercelink/apps/AVWOITEMS.py", line 60, in start
    batch_items["create"].append(product_check(wooapi, item))
  File "/home/atlsoft/commercelink/apps/AVWOITEMS.py", line 35, in product_check
    return woo.create_product(wooapi, item, category_id)
  File "/home/atlsoft/commercelink/platforms/woo/woo.py", line 179, in create_product
    tag = search_tag(word, api_object)
  File "/home/atlsoft/commercelink/platforms/woo/woo.py", line 86, in search_tag
    tag_data = create_tag(tag_name, api_object)
  File "/home/atlsoft/commercelink/platforms/woo/woo.py", line 65, in create_tag
    tag_data = requests.post("{url}/wp-json/wc/v3/products/tags".format(url=api_object.url), auth=(api_object.consumer_key, api_object.consumer_secret), data=data).json()
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/atlsoft/.virtualenvs/commercelink-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 547, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))
```

If anyone has any ideas on how I can solve it, would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have a guess. It is only a guess though. Does the connection abort happen roughly 30 seconds in? PHP has an automatic timeout to avoid letting scripts get stuck in an endless loop. If this is the case, I would suggest consuming the API in small page sizes with, perhaps, a purposeful close and reopen.

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt so instead of just making a request, I should add some pagination to it?